# Warning: Format Specifies Type Argument Type const char *

Tags: c

```
168:35: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'const char *' [-Wformat]
        while (fscanf(fp, "%49s", buf[len]) != EOF)
                           ~~~~   ^~~~~~~~
                           %49s
```

I'm reading from a file, then sorting:

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int len = 0;

    printf("\nSort\n");
    const char buf[1000][50];
    const char *wordss[1000][50];
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buf[len]) != EOF)
    {
        wordss[len][0] = buf[len];
        len++;
    }

    write_buffer_text_file(wordss, len);
    read_buffer_text_file();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried before: 168:33: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'const char *' [-Wformat]
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buf[len]) != EOF)
                           ~~   ^~~~~~~~
                           %49s                                                   And got the same warning.

Comment: How do you expect us to be able to fix a warning when you don't even show us the cause of the warning. I can see it's related to some code but please provide [mre] so we have something to work with to get context.

Comment: It's what it says! The function wants a `char*`, but you gave it a `const char*` instead. Beyond that hard to know, since you did not provide a [mcve]. `buf[len]` is suspicious (did you mean just `buf`?) but then the compilation error is weird for that anyway

Comment: The error message is telling you that `buf[len]` needs to be writeable for the call to `fscanf()` to succeed. You defined it somewhere as a `const char*` variable, which means it can't be modified. (Edit: Just saw the code you added. Have you tried removing the `const` from `const char buf[1000][50]`?)

Comment: Tip: Avoid comparing a `scanf()` result to `!= EOF`.  Better to use `while (fscanf(fp, "%49s", buf[len]) == 1)`.  Compare to what you want, not just one of many thing you do not want and use a width limit with `"%s"`.  With more complex scans, the difference is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fscanf` will write characters to `buf`.  However you have declared `buf` as `const char[][]`.  The `const` means that it is constant and should not be changed.  You should declare `buf` as `char[][]`.

Comment: 2 days figuring it out, that could it be. Thank you Rob. How did you figure it out so fast?

Comment: @Nick_Nick i have lots of experience with the language.

Comment: @Nick_Nick perhaps he read the error message where it tells you what the problem is